# Aspose tiff Converted PDF Opens in Adobe not Foxit

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, aspose

Hi I'm converting a ton of single page scanned .tiff images to multipage pdf's.  Normally I would use iText or PDFSharp but I was introduced to Aspose and was using it as a test for this project (has some cool features to desaturated image and save space which work very nicely - a tb of tiffs is about 200gb of PDF).  I ran into a weird error:  when the converted pdf is opened in adobe reader its fine however when opened in foxit it looks like a page high bar code ?

For all intensive purposes I used this [code example](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/performance+improvement+while+converting+tiff+to+pdf)

Has any one ran into this issue before ?  This is on newest stable adobe and Foxit versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My name is Nayyer and I am a support developer at Aspose and I take care of Aspose.Pdf product family. As per your problem description, I have converted a sample TIFF image into PDF format using [Aspose.Pdf for .NET 6.9.0](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/entry375025.aspx) and I am able to open the resultant PDF in Foxit Reader 5.3.0.0423 and Adobe Reader 10.1.3 without any problem. Can you please try using the latest release version and in case you still face the same problem, can you please share the source TIFF image so that we can test the scenario at our end. We are sorry for this inconvenience.